# PyQT5 событие только на одну кнопку в программе

Tags: python, pyqt5, события

У меня сделан программный интерфейс, и мне хочется как то добавить событие к кнопке, чтобы на него мышкой не тыкать, а исполнять нужные действия.

```
from MyWidget import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, Qt


class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        # Setting Function
        self.ui.Run.clicked.connect(self.Clickback)
        self.ui.Clean.clicked.connect(self.Cleanback)
        self.ui.Run.keyPressEvent(QtGui.QKeyEvent.Enter)
        self.ui.Output.setText("Привет пользователь, я консоль умеющая делать разные фишки в твоей важной жизни\n")
        self.ui.Input.setFocus()

    def Cleanback(self):
        self.ui.Output.setText("Привет пользователь, я консоль умеющая делать разные фишки в твоей важной жизни\n")

    def Clickback(self):
        d = ""
        try:
            d = {
                "hello": "Bye Bye My World\n"
            }[self.ui.Input.text()]
        except:
            self.ui.Output.setText(self.ui.Output.toPlainText() + "Hello\n")

        if d:
            self.ui.Output.setText(self.ui.Output.toPlainText() + d)


if __name__ == "__main__":
     import sys
     app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

     myapp = MyWin()
     myapp.show()

     sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Но не смотря на это у меня выводится ошибка:

```
TypeError: keyPressEvent(self, QKeyEvent): argument 1 has unexpected type 'Type'
```

Comment: Возможно вам поможет `ui.setShortcut('Ctrl+E')`, но этот метод работает только на комбинации клавишь

Comment: Но должен быть же какой то способ автофокуса на кнопку наверное нет? Просто я незнаю, у меня есть сама консоль как раз и я хочу по нажатию кнопки Enter кнопка сработала и вызвала функцию по клику. Но с комбинацией конечно сложновато...

Comment: Вам `keyPressEvent` надо не вызывать, а переопределить. И уже там написать делаемое поведение.

Comment: Вот оно оказывается что... Ну тогда ладно, поищу теперь как это сделать, а так спасибо

Answer (score 2):

События нужно посылать через метод `sendEvent`, причем в случае с кликом на клавишу, нужно посылать два события: нажатие на кнопку (`QKeyEvent.KeyPress`) и отпускание (`QKeyEvent.KeyRelease`).

```
def key_press_release(widget, key, modifier=Qt.NoModifier):
    """
    Функция для отправления события нажатия кнопки.
    # Имитация нажатия на пробел:
    key_press_release(widget, Qt.Key_Space)
    """

    key_press = QKeyEvent(QKeyEvent.KeyPress, key, modifier, None, False, 0)
    QApplication.sendEvent(widget, key_press)

    key_release = QKeyEvent(QKeyEvent.KeyRelease, key, modifier, None, False, 0)
    QApplication.sendEvent(widget, key_release)
```

Для примера из вопроса клик на <kbd>Enter</kbd> выглядел бы так:

```
key_press_release(self.ui.Run, Qt.Key_Enter)
```

---

[Минипример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/cd169e0a152acf013b2b27f99dcef3392d32cc73/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/send_QKeyEvent__auto_click_button.py) на [pyqt5](/questions/tagged/pyqt5), в котором создается кнопка и таймер. Таймер будет вызывать `key_press_release`, а тот создавать события клика на кнопку.

Использовал клик на <kbd>Space</kbd>, потому что на него кнопка как раз сработает:

```
from PyQt5.Qt import Qt, QKeyEvent, QApplication, QPushButton, QTimer


def key_press_release(widget, key, modifier=Qt.NoModifier):
    ...


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    button = QPushButton('Click!')
    button.clicked.connect(lambda: print('Hello World!'))
    button.show()

    timer = QTimer()
    timer.timeout.connect(lambda: key_press_release(button, Qt.Key_Space))
    timer.setInterval(1000)
    timer.start()

    app.exec()
```

---

[Еще пример: посылание виджету событий случайных кликов](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/c7c6d5a70116bc713d54eab871638245c9645e7c/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/send_QKeyEvent/send_key.py#L11)